# typeerror: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

When I tried to run a Python script in Python 2.6.6, it was perfect. But when I run it in Python 2.7.5, I always got the following error.

What's the problem I have?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mqtt-mysql.py", line 204, in <module>
S_UNIQUE = get_setting("unique", F_UNIQUE)
File "mqtt-mysql.py", line 65, in get_setting
cur.execute("SELECT state FROM settings WHERE setting = %s", (setting))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in    execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try string.format() to format your string like `'{0} {1} {2}'.format(obj1, obj2, obj3)`

version<=2.6 and 3.0

`cur.execute("SELECT state FROM settings WHERE setting = {0}".format(setting))`

version>=2.7 and >=3.1

`cur.execute("SELECT state FROM settings WHERE setting = {}".format(setting))`

if you are using 2.6 and 3.0, you need to put the number in placeholder {}. for 2.7 and 3.1 above, the number in the {} can be omitted.

Comment: when I use cur.execute("SELECT state FROM settings WHERE setting = {}".format(setting)), I got the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt-mysql.py", line 204, in <module>
    S_UNIQUE = get_setting("unique", F_UNIQUE)
  File "mqtt-mysql.py", line 65, in get_setting
    cur.execute("SELECT state FROM settings WHERE setting = {}".format(setting))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36,

Comment: [following above comment] in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique' at line 1")

Comment: The resolution only get your TypeError fixed. You need to check your SQL syntax. your SQL query statement might be incorrect. Thanks.